# How to calculate the current rating of a surface contact between a pogo pin and a female receptacle?

Tags: current, connector, pogo-pins

Here is my problem: I have a [pogo pin](https://www.mill-max.com/products/pin/0850/0850-0-15-20-83-14-11-0) that I'd like to use, which is rated for 11 amperes. I also found a [female receptacle for pogo pins](https://www.mill-max.com/products/pin/1943/1943-0-00-15-00-00-03-0?s_term=%201943-0-00-15-00-00-03-0%20&s_type=Quick%2FProduct%2FPart%20Number%20Search), which while not having a current rating, I believe is safe to assume is at least the same 11 amperes for which the pogo pin is rated.

The question is: How can I know if the connection between these two components is rated for 11 amperes? If not, how can I calculate its real current rating? I know that the current rating for this connection is a function of the surface area of the contact patch between the components, but beyond a computer simulation, something like that is very difficult to estimate. Is there another way?

Comment: <<<  I know that the current rating for this connection is a function of the surface area of the contact patch >>> And the "spring" ...

Comment: True, but that is outside of the equation, as its already confirmed by the manufacturer that the pogo pin is capable of 11A. It's the physical connection between the pin and the receptacle that I am worried about.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use a pogo pin for such high current applications. That is not what they are designed for. Note that it says "@ 30˚ C Temp. Rise" and "20% De-rated Maximum Current = 8.80A". That's "cover your ass" language for "we tried it in a lab and it worked during a short test, but your experience may vary".

It may work for a bit, but eventually the spring may weaken due to the high temperature and the contact point resistance will increase, leading to a vicious cycle of ever increasing temperature.

If you absolutely need a spring-loaded connection, consider instead a component designed for high power. For example, the fork contacts used in power tool batteries, or the [blade contacts for laptop batteries](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/blade-type-power-connectors/blade-type-power-connector-assemblies/357).

For greater reliability, lower temperature rise, and more distributed heat generation, rather than using a single contact, use multiple contacts in parallel.

But, in most cases, what works better than a spring-loaded connection is a gendered connector with blade contacts. [For example](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NNK&n=hi_pwr_b2b_conn)  (my site)

Comment: Ok, that makes a lot of sense. I'll re-engineer my solution to use a different connector. I was already looking at powertool-style blade connectors, so I believe I will go for that. Also, I've been using your website for quite a while, works very well :p

Comment: Thank you! Glad to be of help.

Answer (score -1):

You didn't give your rated voltage. The rated voltage of a general pogo pin connector is a maximum of 36V and a current of 2A. Reference: [standard pogo pin](https://www.hktop-link.com/products/pogo-pin), but you need a high current pogo pin of 11A, which must be specially customized. The structure, material and surface plating are different from ordinary pogo pin connectors. Of course, the cost is also higher than ordinary ones. We have been making pogo pins for 18 years. If you need help, please contact us. It is best to tell you what product is used on it. Yes, we can provide technical solutions that suit you.